# Plots in dismo using knitr are preceded with white space

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm using knitr and the dismo package within RStudio. Try as I might I cannot get a plot created using gmap to appear immediately after the text within the R markup.

Here's a screenshot
[image: Example showing extra white space]

And here is a minimal bit of R markup that can be used to recreate it. You'll need to install the three referenced packages.

I'm using RStudio and I'm doing the knitr command within this environment.

````
---
title: "gmap"
output: html_document
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dismo)
library(rgdal)
library(XML)
```
The plot should follow this text
```{r plot, fig.align='left', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
g = gmap('Australia')
plot(g)
```
and precede this. Try as I might, there is white space between the start text and the image which I cannot get rid of.
````

I cannot find any way to control the height of the image using knitr instructions and Google offers no obvious answers. Has anyone seen this before and can offer any advice?

Edit: I have a workaround that plots to a png file and then includes it. This avoids the problem but is clunky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `fig.keep='last'` in the header of the chunk where the map is generated. It seems that two figures are generated during the call of the function `gmap()`. you can see that if you look in the source code of the html page. I don't know when and where the blank image is generated (knit(), gmap(), ??). However the option `fig.keep='last'` should fix the issue only keeping the second figure (the map).

````
```{r plot, echo=FALSE,results='asis', fig.keep='last', fig.align='right'}
g = gmap('Italia')
plot(g)
```
````